# What can I do in a signal handler?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
struct sigaction newSignalAction;
memset(&newSignalAction, 0, sizeof(newSignalAction));
newSignalAction.sa_handler = &SignalHandler;
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &newSignalAction, NULL);

[TestFlight takeOff:@"etc etc etc"];
```

Then

```
void SignalHandler(int sig) {
    NSLog(@"Boom");
}
```

I tried to perform a `SIGSEGV` signal:

```
int *p = NULL;
*p = 1;
```

But my handler is not called. Instead, Xcode points out the line `*p = 1`.

I have read that you can't print stuff with a signal handler. Maybe that's the problem. What **can** I do then? I heard that you're supposed to save data - so I guess I can create files in the Documents directory. I tried to do that, too, but the files are not created either.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside the signal handler, to see if it's being executed? If not, the signal you get may not be `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: I used your code (without `TestFlight` stuff) and I got the `Boom`. What I do is, I didn't run it in XCode, instead I ran it from terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To a close approximation you can't do anything in a signal handler. The problem is that the code interrupted by the signal might be holding locks. If your handler tries to take the same locks then it deadlocks.

The `sigaction` man page lists the functions that are officially approved for use in a signal handler. The list is short. Neither `NSLog()` nor Objective-C method dispatch is in that list.

However, if `NSLog()` doesn't deadlock then it should print output as usual. Perhaps your crash is `SIGBUS` instead of `SIGSEGV`. Perhaps the compiler optimizer is transforming your `*NULL=1` so that it crashes in a different way. Perhaps TestFlight installs its own signal handler that replaces your signal handler.